# maven plugin dependencies forced to be plugins

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm making a new maven plugin.
It basically just allows a program in a JAR that is published to a local maven repo to be run during maven lifecycle.

As such, the plugin requires that JAR and it is listed as a dependency. In the target computers (which do not have the JAR installed), during the maven dependency plugin execution, it will try to download that JAR from the plugins repo. This is where it fails.

When the JAR is tried to be downloaded from the repo, the wrong JAR URL is used. Instead of using the URL to download lib dependencies, it uses the URL to download plugins.

How can I set maven so maven downloads the JAR it depends on using the libs URL instead of the plugins url, when it is ran as a maven plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all it seems, maven plugin dependencies are not forced to be plugins. What really happens is that maven plugin dependencies are searched in plugin repositories.

In my case, to fix this, I added the repositories I had specified in `<repositories>` and copied them to inside the `<pluginRepositories>` while replacing `<repository>` with `<pluginRepository>`.

Note: The settings file is found in `~/.m2/settings.xml` or `%userprofile%\.m2\settings.xml` depending on the OS.